# Wifi Reconnect Duration in iOS - IoT Provisioning

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning, iot, access-point

I have an IoT device that broadcasts a Wifi network upon startup. The device then launches a UDP server so a client can connect to it to send over Wifi credentials. I need to be able to check if those Wifi credentials are correct by having the IoT device switch to Station Mode, see if it can connect to the user's AP, then start the IoT device Wifi network and UDP server again to send back a true or false to the user.

Is there a duration of time that an iOS device attempts to reconnect to the last Wifi network it was connected to if it goes away? If so, I would like to check the Wifi credentials on the IoT device in that time period. It seems like there should be a better way. I've read about SmartConfig and WPS or even using Bluetooth as a separate module (not ideal). Has anyone had experience with this?

Comment: Hi, have you gained some experience regarding your question since then?

Comment: Yes, the best IoT devices can act as both an AP and Station simultaneously. No need to worry about the smart phone keeping a connection alive. The ESP8266 can do this and it works great!